# How can I calculate remaining time in hh:mm:ss knowing total steps, current step and duration (milliseconds)?

Tags: c#, datetime, loops, iteration, timespan

Question as title, this is not working, can't understand why:

```
  // Get total steps, current step and duration in milliseconds
  int current = stats[0]; int total = stats[1]; int duration = stats[2];

  // Calculate the time span (of remaining time)
  var remaining = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds((total - current) * duration);

  // Update the label
  label.Text = string.Format("Tempo rimanente: {0}",
    (new DateTime(remaining.Ticks)).ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: _What_ isn't working? What do you expect this to produce and what does it in fact produce? What is the `stats` variable and what does it contain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
(new DateTime(remaining.Ticks)).ToString("hh:mm:ss"));
```

To

```
remaining.Hours + ":" + remaining.Minutes + ":" + remaining.Seconds);
```

OR even:

```
 // Update the label
 label.Text = string.Format("Tempo rimanente: {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}",
    remaining.Hours, remaining.Minutes, remaining.Seconds)
```

Comment: The only problem is, when value of hours, minutes or seconds are less then 10, output is (eg) 0:9:7, quite unreadable...

Comment: just perfect, thanks. Even if I can't understand the formatting {0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}. What it means?

Comment: @Gremo: The number before the colon means which parameter to insert into that position in the string.The number after the colon allows you to specify a format for the number. The `00` means that you want to show the number as two digits with a leading zero if the number inserted is only one digit long. You can use things like `0.00` to show a number to two decimal places. If you replace the zeros with the number sign (#) it will do the same thing but it will not pad it (or force that many decimal places). It's better explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx).

Comment: [This](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) is also a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to convert a `TimeSpan` to a `DateTime` at all? "Remaining time" is a concept which is ideally suited to a `TimeSpan`, not a `DateTime`. You might want to convert it to the "estimated completion time" which *would* be a `DateTime`, but otherwise just use the `TimeSpan`.

Note that in .NET 4, `TimeSpan` gained [custom format abilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx), if you really need them - but I suspect the default format is likely to be okay for you, at least to start with.

Comment: I need it to convert the time span in hh:mm:ss format. Is the calculation right? Because the remaining time shown is wrong...

Comment: @Gremo: It sounds okay... if you could give an example, that would help.